# How to search sent emails as well as inbox in Outlook for Office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, search, office365

In Outlook (Office 365), if I use the search box to search for emails using an email address, it will only search emails received.  It will not search the `Sent Items` folder, even if I select `All Mailboxes`, `Subfolders` or `All Outlook Items`.

[image: Screenshot of search features and settings]

How do I get the search to call up a list of **sent and received** emails using the email address?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue you had. After a lot of back-and-forth (and no help from MSFT docs), the following *seems* to have solved it for me - even though by rights, it should not make a difference.

1. Create an "All mail" search folder (Folder -> New Search Folder -> Create a custom Search Folder -> Choose... -> Browse... -> include "Inbox" and "Sent Items", give the search a name, press OK, and "Yes" to the "..not specified any criteria..." warning, and OK).
2. Go to the newly created search folder, and search by email address there. **This should give you what you're looking for - at least it did for me**
   Note: if I type in the email address and then click the "contact" (in either "from" or "to" format), it won't work. Just have to be the email address as a "plain string")
3. Bonus, and this is what really doesn't make sense to me... **when I search by email in the Inbox, even when using "Current Mailbox" as scope, it now searches both inbox and sent items...

I have no idea if this will work for you or not, so super interested to hear your feedback on this. If it doesn't work, I'll try to come up with the other things I've tried to get to a point where it works for me, now...

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, if I can search keywords via All Outlook items, the result will show both sent and received emails; if I need to search for a email address, I need to use advanced search, and it will show both sent and received emails too.

[image]

Comment: What you describe does not do what you suggest.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think I described it very clearly. If you want to search by keyword, "all the items" will show both sent and received emails; If you want to search by email address, you should use advanced search as the screenshot.  ( not like -1)